# How to decrease a number from a variable in the class using different methods to 0

Tags: c#, class, object, methods

My problem is I'm using different methods and trying to decrease an `int` from a variable with a maximum of 15 and a minimum of -100.

**the result that I get**
[image]

**The result that I want**
[image]

I don't know if my logic is wrong but that what I came up with:

Code is updated "It works ^_^"

```
using System;

class GamePlayer
{
    private string PlayerName;
    private int _strength;
    private int _Agility;
    private int _Intelligence;
    private int _attributes;
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return PlayerName;
        }
        set
        {
            PlayerName = value;
        }

    }

    public int strength
    {
        get
        {
            return _strength;
        }
        set
        {
            _strength = value;
        }
    }

    public int Agility
    {
        get
        {
            return _Agility;
        }
        set
        {
            _Agility = value;
        }


    }

    public int Intelligence
    {
        get
        {
            return _Intelligence;
        }
        set
        {
            _Intelligence = value;
        }

    }

    public int attributes
    {
            get
            {
                return _attributes;
            }
            set
            {
                _attributes = value;
            }

        } 


    class GFG
    {

        
      //  public static int attributes = 15;
        static public void Main()
        {
            var p = new GamePlayer();
            player(p);
            Strength(p);
            Agility(p);
            Intelligence(p);
            ShowReult(p);


        } 

        static void player(GamePlayer p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name of the Adventurer");
            p.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            p.attributes = 15;

        }
        static void Strength(GamePlayer p)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSet your attributes. Maximum of 5 points each. " + p.attributes);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your Strength: ");
                p.strength = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (p.strength <= 5)
                {
                    p.attributes = p.attributes - p.strength;

                }
                else if (p.strength > 5)
                {

                    while (p.strength > 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[PLEASE CHOOSE LOWER NUMBER]");
                        Strength(p);

                    }

                }
                
            }catch (Exception ex){

                Console.WriteLine("[ONLY NUMBERS PLEASE]");
                Strength(p);

            }
        }
        static void Agility(GamePlayer p)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSet your Agility. Maximum of 5 points each. You have " + p.attributes + " points left");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your Agility: ");
                p.Agility = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (p.Agility <= 5)
                {
                    p.attributes = p.attributes - p.Agility;

                }
                else if (p.Agility > 5)
                {

                    while (p.Agility > 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[PLEASE CHOOSE LOWER NUMBER]");
                        Agility(p);

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("[ONLY NUMBERS PLEASE]");
                Agility(p);

            }
        }
        static void Intelligence(GamePlayer p)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSet your attributes. Maximum of 5 points each. " + p.attributes);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your Intelligence: ");
                p.Intelligence = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (p.Intelligence <= 5)
                {
                    p.attributes = p.attributes - p.Intelligence;

                }
                else if (p.Intelligence > 5)
                {

                    while (p.Intelligence > 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[PLEASE CHOOSE LOWER NUMBER]");
                        Intelligence(p);

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("[ONLY NUMBERS PLEASE]");
                Intelligence(p);

            }
        }

        static void ShowReult(GamePlayer p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("Name of the Adventurer is: " + p.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("point left: " + p.attributes);
            Console.WriteLine("Strength: " + ( p.strength));
            Console.WriteLine("Agility: " + ( p.Agility));
            Console.WriteLine("Intelligence: " + p.Intelligence);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There's a handful of issues here, but I'd say your main problem is you are creating a new `GamePlayer` in each private method, then losing the reference to it.

Comment: I think you are right, I actually had doubt to do it that way but I don't know how to use a single object for different methods.

Comment: **handful of issues** well I think my logic is wrong here?

Comment: The other major issue is you're not actually reducing `attribures` value. You're just displaying 15 - the attribute value. You want to 1) show the value they gave 2) update the value like `attribures -= givenValue` 3) add checks in there to ensure the value they gave isn't more than the max/current value.

Comment: yeap I got what u said and I fixed the code " the code is updated " thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to use a single object in your scenario here is, to create the GamePlayer in your main method and pass it to all other functions:

```
class GFG
{
    public static int attribures = 15;
    static public void Main()
    {
      var p = new GamePlayer();
      player(p);
      
      ...
    } 

    static void player(GamePlayer p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name of the Adventurer");
        p.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Name of the Adventurer is: " + p.Name);
    }
}
```